# How to get existing keystore password?

Tags: react-native

*I have keystore however I forget password of it so I cant get apk in react-native.
Is there a way to find password of keystore file ?*

Answer (score 0):

You can apply bruteforce, dictionary, mixed strategies with software tools like [Android Keystore Password Recovery](https://maxcamillo.github.io/android-keystore-password-recover/): anyway it will require time.

In the event that you are in the need of updating an app in Play store, consider also asking for an upload key reset by Google, by providing a new `upload_certificate.pem` from fresh keystore to them.